# asp.net core identity claims vs properties (efficiency point of view)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

i've read all the tutorials and questions asked about the subject but they contradict one another

claims(userclaims and roleclaims) are serialised into a cookie (along with custom identity user properties you specify by overriding the principle factory) but they don't get queried, they're stored in a cookie, **which mean that the more claims a user have, the more data will have to round trip between the server and browser**

a custom identity user property by default don't get serialised but get queried from the database, so every time you need that data it query it from the database **which is more work to do on the database on each request if you frequently query for it**

so which is more efficient and which is safer

for instance

IsAdmin should be a role/claim? but then if someone stole the cookie, nah nah, the cookie already contains userid/username/securitystamp, so even if it's a property, the userid on the stolen cookie would query on the custom identity user property, or is there something that will prevent this cookie from working when stolen ?

another instance

if i've 20 property for the user (first name, last name, address 1, address 2, postal code, whatever the case may be), should i simply have the user wait a bit for a bigger slower cookie to be send back and forth or should i do all the work from the db using custom identity user

but then, if i remove or add a claim to the user, would it be updated on the next request if it doesn't get queried or is the security stamp validate that this cookie is still valid ?

cause at the `Task AddClaimsAsync` of the userstore of efcore it only add the claim to the dbset

i apologize i know this is many questions to ask but the resources on the matter are not that good and one can easily get lost reading the identity source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb - put frequently added items as a claim, everything else can live in DB and be queried on demand. I.e. address 1, address 2 can't be required on every request, so keep them in the DB.

On the other hand `IsAdmin` (should be a role anyway) I can imagine will be checked on every request, so it should be in the cookie without having to query the db.

If you afraid of your cookies getting stolen, <s>don't show them to anyone!</s> set up `SecurityStampValidator` to do frequent checks - like every 5 minutes. This basically updates the cookie with the fresh information from your database and changes the cookie. So even if the cookie is stolen, it will only work for 5 minutes.

Comment: would you give me more examples for what could be stored in a claim, i still can't imagine what could be put as claim, also could i check if the cookie last ip changed to render this cookie useless if stolen?

Comment: As I said, whatever information is required often enough - put it into the cookie. Like `PersonId` (if different from userId), `TeamId` - I use it in my system to decide permissions. You can also put IP in cookie and have a filter on IP, but I wouldn't do it - think about mobile users whose IP address may change frequently. Just refresh the cookie with `SecurityStampValidtor` every 2 minutes and that's pretty much fixes the stolen cookie problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the two statements contradict, it depends on your configuration. The second statement mentions *"by default"*.

You do not need to store all information in claims nor do you need all the information all the time. If you want profile information, call the server once and store the information on the client, or get it when needed only.

The same counts for authorization, in case you want to show / hide elements based on permissions. This may include a tag called "IsAdmin". Authorization should be kept close to the resource.

If your client wants to refresh the information, just call the server. Claims are not updated during each request. In general, the user has to log out and log in again. So Claims are not flexible and therefor not really suitable for properties that can change (frequently).

As for safety, it doesn't really matter that the client can alter the information, it is for display only. It doesn't change the permission in the backend.

You can consider to add something like a display name to the properties, if you are showing that in every page. You can also consider to implement caching to limit database calls. In the end it really depends on your requirements.

As for stolen cookie, you'll need to implement additional security to your server to detect suspicious behaviour. You may want to include the ip address as claim. As for the admin, add security, e.g. filter by ip address  and / or use an additional code which was send by email.